# Specifying parts from lists for plotting using Show

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following data:

```
  setA = {
  {875, 0.399483}, 
  {880, 0.391583}, 
  {885, 0.383609}};
  setB = {
  {645, 0.690354}, 
  {650, 0.685416}, 
  {655, 0.680413}};
```

I'm trying to plot the data from both sets on the same plot. I can do the following:

```
var[set_,col_] := set[[All, col]];

setAx = var[setA,1]; setAy = var[setA,2]; 
setBx = var[setB,1]; setBy = var[setB,2];
```

then plot:

```
valplot[var1_, var2_, opts_] := 
ListPlot[Transpose[{var1, var2}], PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Red}, Joined -> False, opts]

setsAandBPlots = GraphicsGrid[{
                  {setAyPlot = valplot[setAx, setAy, AxesLabel -> {"variable x", "variable y"}]}

                    (* ,etc... *)
                    }, ImageSize -> 300]
```

This is pretty clunky, I know (i'm very new to programming - and i'm starting with mathematica...).

I want to make a series of these plots comparing different sets (and the *actual* datasets i'm using are much larger than these - many more rows and columns)

I would like to be able plot multiple subsets (e.g. "(setAx and setbx) versus (setAy and SetBy)", etc...) on the same plots (defined by different colored markers) using something like "Show". There must be a neat(er) way to do it using, say, "Position" and "Intersection" to pick the individual values for plotting.

I guess I'm asking if any one can help me find a more general/programatic way to populate the lists "setAx, setAy,setBx, etc..." without having to write them out long-hand?

Cheers!

EDIT:

Sorry I oversimplified my data. It looks more like this:

```
setA = {{8.0, 830, 0.466626, 1.720689,0.200740, 0.018637, 0.009023, 0.029482, 0.091949, 0.074304, 0, 0}, 
        {8.0, 835, 0.459588, 1.742870, 0.202380, 0.019201, 0.010261, 0.032965, 0.093269, 0.074717, 0, 0}}; 
setB = {{8.0, 845, 0.445114, 1.787952, 0.205660, 0.020367, 0.013240, 0.041201, 0.095895, 0.075504, 0, 0}, 
        {8.0, 850, 0.437659, 1.810861, 0.207301, 0.020968, 0.015022, 0.046038, 0.097197, 0.075877, 0, 0}};
```

so, the data is essentially of the form {{A1x, A1y, A1z,…},{A2x,…}}; {{B1x, B1y, B1z,…},{B2x,…}};.

I'd like to be able to plot various combinations with axes: x vs. z, y vs. z etc. ListPlot alone won't help me do this... hence the use of new lists of the form Transpose[{Ax, Az}] etc..

Comment: Are you sets of the form `{x, y1, y2, ...}` ?

Comment: How does the approach `ListPlot[{setA, setB}]` work for you ?

Comment: ListPlot supports plotting of multiple lists, as image_doctor points out, see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html, so plotting of your reference data works fine.

Comment: b.gatessucks, essentially yes. Sorry I over simplified my data.

Comment: I _think_ I understand listplot. Please see below for an example of what my actual datasets look like. Nasser, Union seems to combine the lists so I lose the independence of the sets...

Comment: It is still not very clear, at lease to me, what you want. How many datasets in setA?

Comment: @TomD SetA represents one dataset. The actual values are pressure (e.g. 8 kbars), temperature (e.g. 830 degC), H2O content, SiO2 content, Al2O3 content, etc... setA and SetB (not their real names) are output from the equilibrium thermodynamic software package [THERMOCALC](http://www.metamorph.geo.uni-mainz.de/thermocalc/) with slightly different values for the input bulk composition. DimG's answer essentially solved my problem. My aim is to compare the results of two model runs. I'm still interested in getting a more *general* approach that is applicable to a wider variety of data structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for x vs y plot:

```
ListPlot[setA[[All,{1,2}]],setB[[All,{1,2}]]]
```

where

```
setA[[All,{firstAxe,secondAxe}]]
```

is a list of point coordinates with respect to what you specify by {firstAxe,secondAxe}.

X axe stands for 1, Y for 2 and Z for 3.

Comment: Thanks! this is not quite the way I was thinking of solving the problem but it works fairly nicely. however i needed to change your code to: `ListPlot[{setA[[All,{1,2}]],setB[[All,{1,2}]]}]` (i.e. add curly brackets) in order to compile.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward approach to answering the main part of your question, i.e. "..plot multiple subsets..using something like `Show`" is to use `ListPlot` on a list of data, see the manual on [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
setA = {{875, 0.399483}, {880, 0.391583}, {885, 0.383609}};
setB = {{645, 0.690354}, {650, 0.685416}, {655, 0.680413}};

ListPlot[{setA, setB}]
```

which gives you a diagram like this: 
[image]

`ListPlot` automatically gives the data sets different colors and you can use other functions such as [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tooltip.html), [`StatusArea`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StatusArea.html) and [`Annotation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Annotation.html) to add interactive labeling.

To automatically populate the lists from a source outside of Mathematica, I can recommend this post about [getting data from Excel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8706/1635).

Comment: @FerdrikD, thanks for your answer, not quite what i'm after (see edit). Thanks for the link to the excel import question (it could come in handy). The data in this case do not come from excel. I tend to use textwrangler to format data for input.